# SharePoint Online View -Conditional Formatting: Format Totals?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

Using SharePoint Online, I have a SharePoint view that uses totals on on the columns.  I want to format the Totals row based on if it is a positive or negative value.  Is this possible?

[image: Picture of the SharePoint View]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no OOTB solution for that (for the moment), But you can implement your idea using SPFx, by adding some CSS Styles if that suit you